# Handsontable: How to post the data as an associative array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, handsontable

Using handsontable, you are supposed to be able to [post with ajax](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/tutorial-load-and-save.html#page-onchange) by including the data like so:

```
    data:  {data: myHandsOnTable.getData()},
```

see [getData()](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/Core.html#getData)

But this posts the data as an indexed array, eg:

```
[
  0=> "data"
  1=> "moreData"
]
```

How would I go about posting the data as an associative array with the column indexes as the keys? eg:

```
   [
      "name"=> "data"
      "email"=> "moreData"
    ]
```

Idealy there would be a built-in way to do this, eg something like: `getDataAssoc()` that would add the column key as the key. Rather than having to add a function to loop over and rebuild the data prior to posting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to a later version of handsontable, you can use the [getSourceData](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.21.0/Core.html#getSourceData) method. That should get you the data in the format you're looking for. It returns your original data object, and any changes that occurred in the table will be applied.

Comment: Wow thanks =D, if I can really just drop this in instead of getData that will be useful. They should mention it up in their getting started Load and Save section. I'll try er' out and accept if it works.

Comment: yes could literally just swap out the getData() with getSourceData()

Comment: Here is an answer that could be useful to get the data object https://forum.handsontable.com/t/how-to-get-the-data-object-in-the-handsontable-not-a-two-dimensional-array/3612/2